# returning a file from a non main function to main and then pass it to other function in c

Tags: c, file, input, output

thank you for taking your time to help me with my problem. The problem basically is that I am supposed to have two functions and a main function. The first function is supposed to open a file a second function is supposed to put them into two dynamic arrays.

I have found useful article on how to use a file as a parameter for other function but that solves only half of my problem. The thing I can not help myself with is actually opening it in a non-main function a returning it back to main and sending it to different non-main function.

Comment: just return the FILE* pointer from the function that opened the file

Comment: In order to return it the function has to be of a specific type, what type would it be in this case?

Comment: it would be `FILE*`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need something like this

```
 FILE *openFile(){
    FILE * f = fopen("myfile","r");
    return f;
 }
```

then do

```
FILE* f = openFile();
int c = fgets(f);
...
```

Comment: Okay, great, thank you but that how do I work with the returned value. What I had learned is  (for example) to print out the file this way
`c = fgetc(file);
    while (c != EOF)
    {
        printf ("%c", c);
        c = fgetc(file);
    }`
So if I understand this correctly because I return the file from other function
`c = fgetc(openFile);
    while (c != EOF)
    {
        printf ("%c", c);
        c = fgetc(openFile());
    }`
Thank you for your response :)